# Yii2 Pagination

Tags: yii2, pagination

Приветствую, хочу сделать количество статей на одной страничке - динамической( чтобы пользователь сам выбирал ), но никак не могу додуматься, как именно это сделать.
Пишу на basic шаблоне. 
Вот код пагинатора в контроллере:

```
if($AllPosts)
    {
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $AllPosts->count(), 'pageSize' => $postPerPage]);
        $posts = $AllPosts->offset($pages->offset)
            ->limit($pages->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'pages' => $pages,
        ]); 
    }
```

Вот вызов из вьюшки:

```
<?= \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([ 'pagination' => $pages ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать форму на странице с записью, в которой будут указывать кол-во записей, или дроп-даун, который будет более лучшим решением. Селект в дроп-дауне будет менять урл, например, параметр `page-size`. (Т.е. `URL` у вас должен быть следующего вида: `...\news\?pageSize=COUNT`).

Далее в контроллере вы делаете

```
$pageSize = \Yii::$app->request->get('pageSize');
```

После того, как вы объявили `Pagination`:

```
$pages = $pagination->setPageSize($pageSize);
```

Описал в общем виде. Более подробно об этом написано в документации.